# Implicit does not cause type to be converted when expected

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

```
package com.coryklein.lct.model

import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import language.implicitConversions

class VertexTest extends FlatSpec {

  case class Vertex(x: Double, y: Double)

  implicit def tupleWrapper(tuple: (Double, Double)): Vertex =
    new Vertex(tuple._1, tuple._2)

  "A Vertex" should "be implicitly created from a tuple" in {
    val v: Vertex = (0, 0)
  }

}
```

In this code, the `(0,0)` doesn't get implicitly converted into a `Vertex` as I expect. Why?

Answer (score 3):

See your compiler error:

```
Error:(17, 21) type mismatch;  found   : (Int, Int)  required: VertexTest.this.Vertex
    val v: Vertex = (0, 0)
                    ^
```

The type of `(0,0)` is `(Int,Int)` which does not match the definition of the implicit you created which is `(Double,Double)`, therefore your implicit cannot be applied.

To resolve your problem, change the types to match or define a new implicit conversion.